# How can I make a value reference the size of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a value in a table reference the size of another table.

So if I have a table users:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Alice |
| 2  | Bob   |
+----+-------+
```

and a table statistics:

```
+----+-----------------+-------+
| id | statistic       | value |
+----+-----------------+-------+
| 1  | number_of_users | 2     |
+----+-----------------+-------+
```

If I added a user to statistics is there some way
to make the number_of_users statistic automatically
increase? Maybe by making it a reference to the number
of rows in the users table or something like that.

My goal is to make it so I don't have to change the statistics
table manually every time I add a user.

Comment: I think a `view` might make more sense for this. . .

Comment: You can't reference table metadata automatically, but you could COULD put triggers on the `users` table to capture insert/delete queries and update the stats table as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imbed this where you want the count:
`( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users )`
It will evaluate as the query runs.  Example:

```
SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Students ) AS NumStudents,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Teachers ) AS NumTeachers;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- Create for every table a trigger in INSERT and DELETE to write on your counter table
- Try this query:

  ```
  SELECT table_name, table_rows
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_schema = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
  ```

It returns for every table all rows number.

Comment: If it is InnoDB, the resulting value is only _approximate_.